# Write a matrix in two columns

Tags: r, output

I am wondering whether I can display my long matrix in two columns so it takes less page length:

```
a=matrix(runif(100*3), ncol=3)
```

Output this as two columns of length 50.

Comment: You mean a matrix of 50 rows and 6 columns?

Comment: 150/2 != 50. You will have to rethink your problem.

Comment: You can convert your matrix to a vector and display how many columns you want using `ncol`, for example `matrix(c(a), ncol = 2)` or `matrix(c(a), ncol = 6)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "display".  You could chop the matrix in half, and then put the two halves together, side by side.

```
half <- dim(a)[1]/2
cbind(a[1:half, ], a[half+(1:half), ])
```